# Debugging data structure errors in BigQuery

Tags: debugging, error-handling, google-bigquery

BigQuery often ends `bq load` with ambiguous

```
Waiting on <jobid> ... (68s) Current status: DONE   
BigQuery error in load operation: Error processing job
'<jobid>': Too many errors
encountered. Limit is: {1}.
```

When I do `bq --format=prettyjson show -j <jobid>` to find out what's wrong, I get:

```
  "status": {
    "errorResult": {
      "message": "Too many errors encountered. Limit is: {1}.", 
      "reason": "invalid"
    }, 
    "errors": [
      {
        "message": "Too many errors encountered. Limit is: {1}.", 
        "reason": "invalid"
      }
    ], 
    "state": "DONE"
  },
```

Which usually indicates that `bq` dislikes something about the data structure.

But how can I find out what is wrong? Which row or column `bq` exits on with error?

### Update

Apparently, sometimes, `bq` returns "Failure details", where it says which column and line caused an error. But I couldn't replicate getting these details. They appear arbitrary on the same instance, data, and command.

I found a few options in `bq help load` to let the data pass through:

```
  --[no]autodetect: Enable auto detection of schema and options for formats that are not self
    describing like CSV and JSON.
  --[no]ignore_unknown_values: Whether to allow and ignore extra, unrecognized values in CSV or
    JSON import data.
  --max_bad_records: Maximum number of bad records allowed before the entire job fails.
    (default: '0')
    (an integer)
```

They allow dropping bad values, but many rows may be lost. And I couldn't find where `bq` returns the number of dropped rows.

Comment: Do you have a job id? It might help when I ask internally to the team.

Comment: @FelipeHoffa It's `bqjob_r5cc911c24907bfb8_00000154bbed419a_1`. Thanks!

Comment: I'll file a bug to see if we can improve the error reporting. If it helps, it appears that the (first) failure was on line 2,964. Until then -- for debugging, it might be easier to allow a large number of errors and compare the line counts to see how many were dropped.

Comment: @AdamLydick Thanks! I have a dozen files like this, so it seems I'll have to lose rows. Does `nullable` mode allow keeping the row and going through a particular value at the same time?

Comment: I wouldn't recommend this for production data, but in the absence of more detailed error feedback it could help you narrow down why a particular row isn't getting parsed by BigQuery (so that you can work around it for now). A frequent culprit is string escaping gone wrong.

Comment: Autodetect is probably worth a try, if you aren't already using it (it helps eliminate subtle errors in defining your  schema, especially one that wide). If you *did* autodetect and get that error, please let me know (that could be a bug into the schema detector).

Comment: @AdamLydick I use the following command: "bq load -F"," --source_format=CSV --skip_leading_rows=1 --encoding=ISO-8859-1 --autodetect --max_bad_records=0 --project_id=gpqueries contracts.raw 2003_All_Contracts_Full_20160515.csv `cat contracts.raw.schema.txt`". It adds rows to the table with existing rows. And it returns an error.

Comment: @AntonTarasenko I opened a bug (but it'll probably be a while before we can make significant improvements here). For now, can you try importing into a *new* table using autodetection? Then you can diff the schemas to see where the mismatch is occurring.